# DriverManager.getConnection() returns null, rather than a connection object

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database via JDBC. Using the following code:

```
Connection c = null;
try {
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     c = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL, userID, password);
 } catch (SQLException se) {
     System.out.println(se.getMessage());
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

For some reason no exception is thrown but `c` remains null - what does this mean?

**Update:**

Turns out we were getting an exception - `Class not found: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"` - we had the odbc classes outside the classpath.

Comment: Are you sure that no exception is thrown? What if exception is thrown, but `getMessage()` returns empty string?

Comment: Move the logic of obtaining the connection to a method and throw the exception from there moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have been easier to spot if you handled your exceptions differently. Just printing the exception message and moving on is rarely the right thing to do. What can you do when the database connection is `null`? If you throw an exception indicating that the connection isn't available, then whatever routine is trying to get a connection to the database can alert the user to a potential system outage, log the error, and email a system administrator (for example). Just returning `null` is less obvious to troubleshoot, as you have found.

Comment: Indeed. And even if you were going to return `null`, it'd be better to put the declaration of `c` (perhaps use a better name) within the `try` block and explicitly return in the catch blocks.